# Converting *.pfb files into *.svg files

Tags: java, fonts

### Context

I am interested in *manually* converting *.pfb (Type 1) font files into *.svg files in Java.

I know that

- I can read construct Font objects form *.pfb files in Java
- I can produce GlyphVectors for each character.

### Question

What I don't know is:

- How do I go from GlyphVector to the strokes / paths which I can then output into a *.svg file?

### Aside

This is a learning exercise. I'm re-inventing the wheel on purpose for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to generate an SVG image with all the glyphs in the font or generate an [SVG Font](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html)?

For generating an SVG image, you can use [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/).  Draw each glyph into a Batik graphics context (using [SVGGraphics2D](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html)) and you'll then be able to write an SVG file from Batik.